# How to show Flutter plugin widget in Widget tree

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wrote a Flutter plugin and tested it in the example folder.
The app worked fine, but in the widget tree, I can't see the plugin's widget.

So, Is it possible to show the plugin's code in the widget tree?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `plugin's code` in the widget tree?

Comment: In the plugin, i write some widgets, and use it in my app. And you can see in the image, only widget MaterialApp is shown in widget tree, because it's located in main.dart.
So, is it possible to show the widget in widget tree